# Custom SearchView TextChange

Tags: android, searchview

Hi I have created a Custom SearchView but i cannot receive the entered text by user

this is my view_search.xml

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_input_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/close_search_button"
            android:hint="جستجو..."
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/close_search_button"/>
```

and i put it to toolbar

```
            <ir.mahdi.circulars.CustomView.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/SearchView"
                app:showDividers="none" />
```

and this is my searchview class

```
class SearchView(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs) {

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.view_search, this, true)

    }
```

i dont know how to handle searchview textchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this in Kotlin?

```
var searchView = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.search_input_text)

var searchValue = searchView?.editableText.toString()
```

If you want use listener in Java;

```
 searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {

   }
  });
```